# How to set null JSON values as JMeter variables

Tags: json, jmeter, jsonpath, jmeter-5.0, json-path-expression

For a given sample JSON (this is only an example, the real JSON is much larger):

```
{
  "username":"Admin",
  "text":"test message",
  "attachments":[
    {
      "title":"demo server",
      "title_link":"${link}",
      "text":"sample text",
      "fields": [
        {
            "title":"Stats",
            "value":"Average times",
            "short":true
        },
                {
            "title":"Weather",
            "value":"Fine",
            "short":true
        },
           {
            "title":"Host",
            "short":true
        }
      ],
      "image_url":"",
      "thumb_url":"${thumb_url}",
      "color":"${color}"
    }]
}
```

using JSON Extractor in JMeter 5, with the following settings

`Names of created variables:` set to `title; value`

and

`JSON Path expressions:` set to `$..title; $..value`

I'm able to get the values from the JSON to the JMeter _ALL variables.

The problem is that title_3 doesn't correspond to value_3, because of the different number of values for the corresponding variable name.

How can I set 'value_3' to 'null' in this example?

Comment: "title_3 doesn't correspond to value_3" means "value_3 doesn't exist while title_3 does" - is that correct?

Comment: No, the Thread group is continuously resending the HTTP request and populating the variables. So after 2 runs, I will have title_1, value_1, title_2, value_2, title_3, value_1, title_1, value_2, etc.

Comment: Wow... interesting catch. I never stumble upon anything like this (it seems like a specific feature). But what's the reason behind such a massive extraction vs. assertion? What you do with extracted values?

Comment: It is an exercise project for me. First I want to be able to extract values for a specific JSON field and later compare it with a database data.

Comment: Sounds legit. But you see - it's not a bug, I believe, it's the way it works: if the there's a match - there's a new (next) var, no match - no var produced, and that goes independently of each other. So far, none of a simple solution comes into my mind - except for JMeter's Swiss Army Knife: JSR223 post processor. Given how simple is the way of handling JSON is in Groovy - that's not gonna take a lot of effort.